# Draw tree with leaves at different levels

Tags: forest

I'm trying to draw a tree similar to the one depicted below (content of nodes is different). My leaves are very wide and I need to pack them closer together by "lifting" every other leaf up.

[image: Tree with elevated leaves]

Is it possible to tweak my code below to get my leaves to be on different levels and thus closer together, as depicted above?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}    

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[{$r_{1,8} = p \bmod a_{1,8}$}
    [{$r_{1,4} = r_{1,8} \bmod a_{1,4}$} 
        [{$r_{1,2} = r_{1,4} \bmod a_{1,2}$} 
            [{$r_{1,1} = r_{1,2} \bmod (x-1)$}
                [{$v_1$} ]
            ]
            [{$r_{2,2} = r_{1,2} \bmod (x-2)$}
                [{$v_2$} ]
            ]
        ]
        [{$r_{3,4} = r_{1,4} \bmod a_{3,4}$} 
            [{$r_{3,3} = r_{3,4} \bmod (x-3)$}
                [{$v_3$} ]
            ]
            [{$r_{4,4} = r_{3,4} \bmod (x-4)$}
                [{$v_4$} ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [{$r_{5,8} = r_{1,8} \bmod a_{5,8}$} 
        [{$r_{5,6} = r_{5,8} \bmod a_{5,6}$} 
            [{$r_{5,5} = r_{5,6} \bmod (x-5)$}
                [{$v_5$} ]
            ]
            [{$r_{6,6} = r_{5,6} \bmod (x-6)$}
                [{$v_6$} ]
            ]
        ]
        [{$r_{7,8} = r_{5,8} \bmod a_{7,8}$} 
            [{$r_{7,7} = r_{7,8} \bmod (x-7)$}
                [{$v_7$} ]
            ]
            [{$r_{8,8} = r_{7,8} \bmod (x-8)$}
                [{$v_8$} ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

**Later edit:** I have tried the following.

First, tiering odd and even `r_{i,i}`'s differently.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[{$r_{1,8} = p \bmod a_{1,8}$}
    [{$r_{1,4} = r_{1,8} \bmod a_{1,4}$}
        [{$r_{1,2} = r_{1,4} \bmod a_{1,2}$}
            [{$r_{1,1} = r_{1,2} \bmod (x-1)$},tier=odd
                [{$v_1$} ]
            ]
            [{$r_{2,2} = r_{1,2} \bmod (x-2)$},tier=even
                [{$v_2$} ]
            ]
        ]
        [{$r_{3,4} = r_{1,4} \bmod a_{3,4}$}
            [{$r_{3,3} = r_{3,4} \bmod (x-3)$},tier=odd
                [{$v_3$}  ]
            ]
            [{$r_{4,4} = r_{3,4} \bmod (x-4)$},tier=even
                [{$v_4$} ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [{$r_{5,8} = r_{1,8} \bmod a_{5,8}$}
        [{$r_{5,6} = r_{5,8} \bmod a_{5,6}$}
            [{$r_{5,5} = r_{5,6} \bmod (x-5)$},tier=odd
                [{$v_5$}  ]
            ]
            [{$r_{6,6} = r_{5,6} \bmod (x-6)$},tier=even
                [{$v_6$} ]
            ]
        ]
        [{$r_{7,8} = r_{5,8} \bmod a_{7,8}$}
            [{$r_{7,7} = r_{7,8} \bmod (x-7)$},tier=odd
                [{$v_7$} ]
            ]
            [{$r_{8,8} = r_{7,8} \bmod (x-8)$},tier=even
                [{$v_8$} ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Second, tiering even `r_{i,i}`'s and `v_i`'s differently.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[{$r_{1,8} = p \bmod a_{1,8}$}
    [{$r_{1,4} = r_{1,8} \bmod a_{1,4}$}
        [{$r_{1,2} = r_{1,4} \bmod a_{1,2}$}
            [{$r_{1,1} = r_{1,2} \bmod (x-1)$},tier=odd
                [{$v_1$},tier=last ]
            ]
            [{$r_{2,2} = r_{1,2} \bmod (x-2)$}
                [{$v_2$},tier=last ]
            ]
        ]
        [{$r_{3,4} = r_{1,4} \bmod a_{3,4}$}
            [{$r_{3,3} = r_{3,4} \bmod (x-3)$},tier=odd
                [{$v_3$},tier=last  ]
            ]
            [{$r_{4,4} = r_{3,4} \bmod (x-4)$}
                [{$v_4$},tier=last ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [{$r_{5,8} = r_{1,8} \bmod a_{5,8}$}
        [{$r_{5,6} = r_{5,8} \bmod a_{5,6}$}
            [{$r_{5,5} = r_{5,6} \bmod (x-5)$},tier=odd
                [{$v_5$},tier=last  ]
            ]
            [{$r_{6,6} = r_{5,6} \bmod (x-6)$}
                [{$v_6$},tier=last ]
            ]
        ]
        [{$r_{7,8} = r_{5,8} \bmod a_{7,8}$}
            [{$r_{7,7} = r_{7,8} \bmod (x-7)$},tier=odd
                [{$v_7$},tier=last ]
            ]
            [{$r_{8,8} = r_{7,8} \bmod (x-8)$}
                [{$v_8$},tier=last ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. That's what `tier`s are for. (And if you know German, you understand why I *had* to choose `murmel`. ;-)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}    

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[{$r_{1,8} = p \bmod a_{1,8}$}
    [{$r_{1,4} = r_{1,8} \bmod a_{1,4}$} 
        [{$r_{1,2} = r_{1,4} \bmod a_{1,2}$} 
            [{$r_{1,1} = r_{1,2} \bmod (x-1)$}
                [{$v_1$},tier=murmel ]
            ]
            [{$r_{2,2} = r_{1,2} \bmod (x-2)$},tier=murmel 
                [{$v_2$} ]
            ]
        ]
        [{$r_{3,4} = r_{1,4} \bmod a_{3,4}$} 
            [{$r_{3,3} = r_{3,4} \bmod (x-3)$}
                [{$v_3$},tier=murmel  ]
            ]
            [{$r_{4,4} = r_{3,4} \bmod (x-4)$},tier=murmel 
                [{$v_4$} ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [{$r_{5,8} = r_{1,8} \bmod a_{5,8}$} 
        [{$r_{5,6} = r_{5,8} \bmod a_{5,6}$} 
            [{$r_{5,5} = r_{5,6} \bmod (x-5)$}
                [{$v_5$},tier=murmel  ]
            ]
            [{$r_{6,6} = r_{5,6} \bmod (x-6)$},tier=murmel 
                [{$v_6$} ]
            ]
        ]
        [{$r_{7,8} = r_{5,8} \bmod a_{7,8}$} 
            [{$r_{7,7} = r_{7,8} \bmod (x-7)$}
                [{$v_7$},tier=murmel  ]
            ]
            [{$r_{8,8} = r_{7,8} \bmod (x-8)$},tier=murmel 
                [{$v_8$} ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

ADDENDUM: A version in which all the `v_i` are at the same level but the levels of the nodes above alternate.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}    
\tikzset{bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=0.2pt,outer sep=0pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[{$r_{1,8} = p \bmod a_{1,8}$}
    [{$r_{1,4} = r_{1,8} \bmod a_{1,4}$} 
        [{$r_{1,2} = r_{1,4} \bmod a_{1,2}$} 
            [{$r_{1,1} = r_{1,2} \bmod (x-1)$},tier=faul
                [{$v_1$},tier=murmel ]
            ]
            [,bullet,tier=faul
               [{$r_{2,2} = r_{1,2} \bmod (x-2)$},tier=schnabel
                   [{$v_2$},tier=murmel ]
               ]
            ]
        ]
        [{$r_{3,4} = r_{1,4} \bmod a_{3,4}$} 
            [{$r_{3,3} = r_{3,4} \bmod (x-3)$},tier=faul
                [{$v_3$},tier=murmel  ]
            ]
            [,bullet,tier=faul
               [{$r_{4,4} = r_{3,4} \bmod (x-4)$},tier=schnabel 
                   [{$v_4$},tier=murmel ]
               ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [{$r_{5,8} = r_{1,8} \bmod a_{5,8}$} 
        [{$r_{5,6} = r_{5,8} \bmod a_{5,6}$} 
            [{$r_{5,5} = r_{5,6} \bmod (x-5)$},tier=faul
                [{$v_5$},tier=murmel  ]
            ]
            [,bullet,tier=faul
               [{$r_{6,6} = r_{5,6} \bmod (x-6)$},tier=schnabel 
                   [{$v_6$},tier=murmel ]
               ]
            ]
        ]
        [{$r_{7,8} = r_{5,8} \bmod a_{7,8}$} 
            [{$r_{7,7} = r_{7,8} \bmod (x-7)$},tier=faul
                [{$v_7$},tier=murmel  ]
            ]
            [,bullet,tier=faul
               [{$r_{8,8} = r_{7,8} \bmod (x-8)$},tier=schnabel 
                   [{$v_8$},tier=murmel ]
               ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @marmot! This is very useful. Is there a way to use `tier` to line up the `v_i` leaves on the same row, while still keeping the second-to-last level "compressed" (as depicted in your picture)?

Comment: @AlinTomescu You can have several different `tier`s, e.g. `tier=murmel` for the upper row and `tier=schnabel` for the lower one.

Comment: You mean `murmel` for the level with even `r_{i,i}`'s and `schnabel` for the level with odd `r_{i,i}`s? Or `schnabel` for the level with `v_i`'s?

Comment: @AlinTomescu This is up to you.

Comment: None of them seem to work though. If I set tier=even for `r_{2i,2i}`'s and tier=odd for `r_{2i+1,2i+1}`'s, they both get rendered on the same level (i.e., as in my original code). I get the same result if I set tier=even for `r_{2i,2i}`'s and tier=values for `v_i`'s.

Comment: @AlinTomescu Could you please append to your question what you tried?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87139/discussion-between-alin-tomescu-and-marmot).

Answer (score 2):

I think you could play a bit around with the `l` specification of child leaves. For example, this code does not produce the most "aesthetic" tree but it seems to be a step forward towards what you need. Further details about leaf placement can be found in the [documentation](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf) (page 10 for example)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    [{$r_{1,8} = p \bmod a_{1,8}$}
    [{$r_{1,4} = r_{1,8} \bmod a_{1,4}$} 
    [{$r_{1,2} = r_{1,4} \bmod a_{1,2}$} 
    [{$r_{1,1} = r_{1,2} \bmod (x-1)$}, l = 22mm,
    [{$v_1$} ]
    ]
    [{$r_{2,2} = r_{1,2} \bmod (x-2)$}, l = 12mm,
    [{$v_2$}, l = 15mm ]
    ]
    ]
    [{$r_{3,4} = r_{1,4} \bmod a_{3,4}$} 
    [{$r_{3,3} = r_{3,4} \bmod (x-3)$}, l = 22mm,
    [{$v_3$} ]
    ]
    [{$r_{4,4} = r_{3,4} \bmod (x-4)$}, l = 12mm,
    [{$v_4$}, l = 15mm ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    [{$r_{5,8} = r_{1,8} \bmod a_{5,8}$} 
    [{$r_{5,6} = r_{5,8} \bmod a_{5,6}$} 
    [{$r_{5,5} = r_{5,6} \bmod (x-5)$}, l = 22mm,
    [{$v_5$} ]
    ]
    [{$r_{6,6} = r_{5,6} \bmod (x-6)$}, l = 12mm,
    [{$v_6$}, l = 15mm ]
    ]
    ]
    [{$r_{7,8} = r_{5,8} \bmod a_{7,8}$} 
    [{$r_{7,7} = r_{7,8} \bmod (x-7)$}, l = 22mm,
    [{$v_7$} ]
    ]
    [{$r_{8,8} = r_{7,8} \bmod (x-8)$}, l = 12mm,
    [{$v_8$}, l = 15mm ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]